# View engine error when sending registration email in loopback

Tags: strongloop

I am just kicking off a new project using loopback. I have created a new model based on the standard user model and I am now implementing registration and login by following the tutorials.

I have registration emails configured and sending via Gmail however I get an error in the console -

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

The tutorial uses ejs as the outbound email template and I thought this was the default for loopback so not sure why I would be getting this error.  I have read a couple of posts about changing to jade which talk about configuring (jade) in the server.js file.

My question is should loopback be picking up ejs automatically?

If not and I need to configure it manually is server.js the place to do it or should it be a config file setting e.g. config.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view engine isn't set by default in loopback and you need to set it. To configure EJS template.

Since `loopback` is based on express. So you need to follow the express approach to set the `view engine`.

1. First `install` the EJS template.

   `$ npm install ejs --save`

   Also open terminal go to the root folder and type.

   `$ mkdir views && mkdir views/static`

   Here `views/` folder will be the base folder for the Views and `views/static` will be the base folder for serving static files `css/js/image etc`
2. Now inside the `server/boot/root.js` file. comment the following lines.

   `//var router = server.loopback.Router();`

   `//router.get('/', server.loopback.status());`

   `//server.use(router);`
3. Now add these lines to the `server/boot/root.js` folder

   ```
    module.exports = function(server) {
      var loopback = require('loopback');

    //Now setting up the static files..
    server.use('/static', loopback.static(__dirname + '/../../views/static'));

    // set the view engine to ejs
    server.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    //Now set the index page for the  '/' route
    server.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index', data);
    });

   }
   ```
4. Now finally add a `index.ejs` file to `views/` to load.